# Is there a command to create a local.settings.json file when building an Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I'm building a Azure static web app. I'd like to make use of [app configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings#configure-api-application-settings-for-local-development). I've added several configurations to the UI. Is there a command that I can use to generate a file `local.settings.json` based on the current configurations I've typed into the Azure Portal?

- The documentation lists several examples, which I can cut-and-paste and modify, but I'm not exactly clear what is needed and what isn't. For example, in this example, do I need `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`?
- I'm also curious if such a command exists.
- I've tried things like `az rest --method post --uri "<static app's name in Azure portal>/listFunctionAppSettings"`, but these command fail.

Comment: I found [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local#local-settings-file) explaining the format of `local.settings.json`. I'm still curious if there is a command to export the current settings from azure to a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download application settings using the [Azure Static Web Apps VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestaticwebapps). Navigate to your static web app in the extension list and right click on Application Settings -> Download Remote Settings.